# Unrecognized font family 'anticon' in React-Native (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have used `react-native-vector-icons@^9.2.0` for using vector icons in our applications.

> Node Version: `v16.16.0` ; npm Version: `8.11.0` ; React-Native Version: `0.69.0` ; Pod Version: `1.11.3`

Here is the Process which I have followed,

Firstly, I have Installed `react-native-vector-icons` and then copy the **Fonts** folder from **node_modules/react-native-vector-icons** and then paste it into **projectName.xcworkspace** which opened via Xcode and then manually added Fonts name which is type of **.ttf** extension. and then install the pod using `pod install` command. After added the **Fonts** it automatically added into `info.plist` is given below,

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Then I run the projects but it is occured an error as given in attached file please check it and help me who have knowledge.
[image: react-native-vector-icons error in iOS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it to your assets/ folder, and create this file at the root of your project:

react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./path/to/assets/'],
};
```

Reference: https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Answer (score 0):

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'

Icon.loadFont();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).